# Is there a way to differentiate between query and data conditions

Tags: casl

I have a feathersjs service called `documentations`. When patching a `documentation` the user could set the `editing` field only to his own `user._id` or to `null`. Also the user can only patch `documenations` of his own company.

I have stored my permissions in a MongoDB Database:

```
...
{
  "action": "patch",
  "subject": "documentation",
  "fields": ["editing", "sections", "title", "published"],
  "conditions": {
    "company": "${user.belongsTo}"
  }
}
...
```

Is there a way to implement the `editing` field logic with CASL?

Is there some way to differentiate between query and data conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly speaking this kind of logic in my opinion is BL concern not permissions concern. But you can do smth similar with CASL too, create a separate rule for `editing` field:

```js
can(“update”, “documentation”, { company: ..., editing: { $in: [null, user.id] } }, [“editing”])
```

So, each time you update `editing` just check permissions